# IntelliJ no longer able to read server.xml for Tomcat 7.0.47

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, tomcat7

**What's happening:**

> 12:15:21 PM Error running [ApplicationName]: Cannot load C:\Users\[UserName]\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\[ServerName]\conf\server.xml: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

I'm using the tomcat home for an actual installation of the application I'm maintaining and it starts fine as a windows service.

Server.xml line 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

This hasn't changed in over a year.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried deleting and backspacing, attempting to get rid of non-printable characters.
- I've tried windows vs. linux line endings.
- I've tried re-saving it in UTF-8.
- It worked before sleeping my laptop for the night, but not in the morning.
- I've invalidated the cache, renamed the entire cache folder, upgraded to the latest version of IDEA 14 (14.1.5 #IU-141.2735).
- I've checked out the file from our VCS.
- I've re-added the tomcat server, added additional jars to it.
- I've stashed all of my changes to get back to the last known good configuration for the source and am still unable to start my tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was non-printable characters ahead of the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` tag.  I had to use a hex editor to get rid of them.

[image: HxD showing the leading characters]